# Spring-security, Elastic Load Balancer and sticky sessions

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, load-balancing

I'm currently using Spring and Spring-security to handle
 Authorisation and Authentication.

My app is running behind the ELB that i have configured with Sticky Session (using the Spring's security SESSIONID).  That works fine. but ELB is configured to spawn and delete instances depending on the load.

So if a the User_A's session is on the server C and that this server is terminated .. well then user_A will have to re-login. and we don't what that.

Is there a way with Spring-security to make him use the DB to store the token instead of a InMemory cache ?

Thank you!

Comment: The spring-session project solves this problem. It persists sessions into a reddis instance out of the box. Though I think you can implement a repository for any underlying store.